# Simplex Algorithm (Exercise 3.11.33 in Grimmett and Stirzaker's Probability and Random Processes)

Tags: probability

There are $n \choose m$ points ranked in order of merit with no matches. You seek to reach the best, $B$. If you are at the $j$th best, you step to any one of the $j - 1$ better points, with equal probability of stepping to each. Let $r_j$ be the expected number of steps to reach $B$ from the $j$th best vertex. Show that $r_j = \sum_{k=0}^{j - 1} k^{-1}$. Give an asymptotic expression for the expected time to reach $B$ from the worst vertex, for large $m, n$.

Please can you help me to understand this question? What does the first sentence mean? I think there are $j = {n \choose m}$ vertices and they have been ranked in order from worst to best. But what does the " ... with no matches." mean?

Comment: "with no matches" just means all values are distinct. No two points have equal value.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I was able to prove the expression for $r_j$ after I understood what "... with no matches" meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is straight forward. First show that

$$r_{j + 1} = \frac{1}{j} \sum_{k = 1}^{j - 1} (r_j + 1),$$

using conditional probability and then use induction. For large $j = {n \choose m}$, $r_j \approx \ln j$.